# The answer is a girl's name (my future granddaughter) - can anyone help?

Tags: riddle

> I'm a villain who will have you up the wall.
>   I go into your veins, green, brown - well read.
>   But you have to be great to get into me.

Only other clue I have is it's not related to Game of Thrones...

Comment: Is this a puzzle you created or did you find it elsewhere?

Comment: my daughter has created it

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your daughter and her partner sound like my kind of folks! If you want to know your future granddaughter's name, read on - if you don't want to spoil the surprise, walk away now!

Her name is:

> **IVY**

Why?

*I'm a villain who will have you up the wall.*

> **Poison Ivy** from the Batman series is a villain. Ivy is also a climbing plant, which will climb up walls.

*I go into your veins, green, brown - well read.*

> 'Ivy' sounds like '**IV**', the medical abbreviation for 'intravenous', used for things like drips and cannula-administered medications while in hospital. Ivy (the plant) can also be green or brown in colour.

*But you have to be great to get into me.*

> In the US, **Ivy League** universities/colleges are considered the best of the best, with demanding entrance criteria. Only the 'well read' and academically excellent will 'get in'.

Whether you decided to look or not, enjoy being a grandparent! Good luck!

Comment: @kevinhazard You're very welcome :) Wishing you all a lot of happy times to come!